# How to convert xml to bean with Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

What is the `spring/spring-boot` preferred way of marshalling an `xml` document into a java bean?

This is the bean mapping that I have:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "myroot")
    public class Myroot {
        private String fields;
    }
```

This is the xml file that is read to a `String`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myroot>
   <fields.../>
</myroot>
```

Does spring provide any marshaller that I could use with `@Autowired` and marshal the xml string to bean? Or would I have to create my own marshaller, eg `@Bean Jaxb2Marshaller`?

Comment: Just to be sure I understood your question correctly, you want to create your own xml spring marshaller to create beans at runtime ?

Comment: If I can use any existing spring marshaller I'd be happy to use it. I just want to achieve unmarshalling from xml content to a custom bean. But yes, I want to create those beans at runtime.